# A way to read or assign all unallocated sectors?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

Recently, an error while moving a large file via the network resulted in the original being deleted before the move was complete.

The NTFS drive with the original file on has not been changed since, but for some reason the half-dozen top-ranked undelete utilities cannot recover the file, they see it but as length 0 and fail when attempting to recover it.  I honestly cannot remember their names.  I just went down the list trying them all in order until so many of them gave me the exact same results I was convinced they are basically equivalent to one another and all running into the same problem.

I then used a utility that wrote the entire contents of the drive to an image file, which I examined and found parts of the missing file interspersed with parts of other files on the disk.

Is there a way to read or assign only the sectors that are NOT part of an existing file?

Comment: No. Once the file table entry is removed, nothing knows what part of the file is where. If the file is not contiguous it can’t be recovered.

Comment: So you found parts, even if you could do something with those parts, the file isn’t complete.

Comment: As the file is a video file,and I was only intending to use parts of it anyway, parts of the file would be preferable to no file.  So yet again, I would like a way to read all sectors not allocated to any other file and save these as a file.  I will then see what i can do with the result.  Please do not tell me what I want.   i know what I want.  Please help me get it.

Comment: I experimented with `ntfsfallocate` (in Linux) and created an extra file that claimed the whole unused space. However it appeared to be all zeros, even though the whole image still contained data from recently deleted files (confirmed with `strings /the/image | grep ...`). Maybe I messed something up or misinterpreted. If not, I think there is a (security?) mechanism that prevents a newly created file from reading abandoned content, even if the file has allocated its space without overwriting it. So this approach probably leads to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

First this isn't going to be quick or easy.

Make a backup of the image incase something goes wrong, or more likely you inadvertently make a mistake.

Here is the subtractive process.

If you imaged everything it should be mountable.

Mount it, if you can't do it in windows, linux will do it.  mount -o loop /image.img /mountpoint

Get or write a program do overrite each file with a 0 for the precise number of bytes of the file size.  The program could probably be written in C in 30-60 minutes with a bit of testing included.  Delete the file you just over wrote.

Now repeat for every file in the image.

Except for the deleted data, and a bit of infrastructure the rest of the sector would be 0.

I forgot about zombies.  Sure it will erase all allocated files, but chances are there are gigabytes of file remnant from previously delete files.  Files that were deleted and partially over written and delete and so on to deal with.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that when you overwrite a file with zeros, these zeros will end up in exactly the same sectors? I mean: a clever filesystem may silently defragment the file if there are (formally) free sectors after the previous chunk. I don't know if this is a reasonable idea nor if NTFS is that smart. But are we sure no similar optimization will happen?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski NTFS has no auto defragment at the file system level.  They built that into windows 7 and above.  It is easy to turn it off for a specific drive or all drives.  If you are worried about auto-processes, use linux.  The file system integrity has to be maintained, so defragmenter have to update metadata when changes are made.  The NTFS metadata has no built-in optimization methods.  That is why specific programs like perfect disk by Raxco were written to optimize the metadata.  However, it require a reboot of the system, and running in an offline, chkdsk like mode to do this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If you have defragment running while you are deleting files, it is posssible for defrag to re-use unallocated sectors.  However, just go into Defragment and cancel it.  The default setting is weekly so the odds are in your favor that it is not defragmenting at that time.  Even then every drive I have has violated that basic rule because they all claim 10 or 17 days since last defragmented and it should never exceed 7 or 8 in the worst possible condition.

Answer (score 0):

Even more complex than that, probably taking weeks to complete:

Linux has pre-built libraries for ntfs.  I have never done this so I don't know how easy/hard it would be.

You could in memory decode the NTFS filesystem entries create a list of all used sectors.  Then scan that list for gaps.

Writing said program could take weeks.